# how to debug MSBuild dependency issues?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, c++-cli

We have a mixed C# and C++/CLI solution. Building with devenv works, building via

```
msbuild /nr:false /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 Solution.sln
```

works but fails when adding /m. For example with cl or link failing cause .pch or .obj is already in use.

Via diagnostic output I found out that some projects are built multiple times for whatever reason:

```
1>Project "Solution.sln" (1)
is building "a.vcxproj" (34) on node 2 (default targets).
34>Project "a.vcxproj" (34)
is building "b.vcxproj" (43:2) on node 5 (default targets).
33>Project "c.csproj" (33)
is building "c.csproj" (33:2) on node 6 (ResolveReferences;_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal target(s)).
33:2>Project "c.csproj" (33:2)
is building "d.csproj" (41) on node 2 (default targets).
41>Project "d.csproj" (41)
is building "d.csproj" (41:2) on node 2 (ResolveReferences;_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal target(s)).
41:2>Project "d.csproj" (41:2)
is building "b.vcxproj" (43) on node 2 (default targets).
```

.

```
1>Project "Solution.sln" (1)
is building "e.vcxproj" (60) on node 5 (default targets).
1>Project "Solution.sln" (1)
is building "f.csproj" (69) on node 6 (default targets).
69>Project "f.csproj" (69)
is building "f.csproj" (69:2) on node 6 (ResolveReferences;_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal target(s)).
69:2>Project "f.csproj" (69:2)
is building "e.vcxproj" (60:2) on node 6 (default targets).
```

But I don't know why it behaves like that when devenv is able to get the deps right.

Does any one know other switches/tools/whatever or what to look for in the logs to figure how to fix this?

Comment: how did you set the /M value? If you just use few process like： msbuild xxx.proj /maxcpucount:3, how about the result?  The /ds will give a detailed summary, you can also check it in your side. Please also check the build order for that issue(build multiple times): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/12/21/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe/

Comment: /m uses 8 instances but it happens with /m:2 as well, just with smaller probability of course.
I think I've read that article before. We don't have any .sln file ProjectDependencies. Is that paragraph about the 64bit MSBuild version still valid?

Comment: whether just the mix solution has this issue? Do you build it using the 32 bit version or different platform target? Would you please share a simple sample here?

Comment: At least I can't reproduce it in a small mixed test solution. Must be something special.
It automatically picks the 64bit MSBuild.

Comment: Looks like this package is the root cause: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Clarius.TransformOnBuild-unofficial/
Replacing it with the Modeling SDK's .targets looks promising.

Comment: so it works well after you change the package now, am I right? If so, you could post it as the answer and mark it. So it could help other community members who meet the same issue. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Well there are some problems if you reference another project from the same solution in your .tt file as the transform happens before the dependency is built even though the project reference is properly set up. Replacing <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild> with <Target Name="CustomTransformOnBuild" BeforeTargets="MarkupCompilePass1">... seems to work for x64 but not for x86.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, but the reason why it doesn't work for x86, maybe it is related to the platform target or it just referenced the 64 bit library or others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replacing https://www.nuget.org/packages/Clarius.TransformOnBuild-unofficial/ with the Modeling SDK the problems disappeared.

Regarding MSBuild "debugging" in general it seems like there is no better way than digging through the detailed logs `/fl /flp:MSBuild.log;verbosity=diagnostic /detailedsummary`